# Connect MQTTnet with Azure IoT Hub

Tags: .net-4.5, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, .net-framework-version

I have created a device that delivers messages. Now I want to send them to an **Azure IoT Hub** by using **MQTTnet Version 2.4.0** because the .NET target Framework is on Version 4.5 and it is not my decision to change it.

My Question:

- Is there any other or better method to do this
- What MqttClientOption do I take best
- What Parameters to set to which value to connect to the Hub

I have tried almost every combination of values for the ClientId/UserName/Password as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device

but none of them worked for me

I have tried outside the Project and build a similar device on the current framework and it worked perfectly with the newer version of MQTTnet.

Sadly I don't get any kind of error message only a MqttCommunicationTimedOutException after about 10 seconds.

Thanks for your help I have been stuck at this problem for almost a week.

Comment: why can't you use the IoT Device Client SDK? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client/ You can also specify to send over MQTT when you use the SDK

Comment: I have tried that but there is the same issue of the framework incompatibility

Comment: Can you show your *MqttClientTcpOptions*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet is a working example of the simulated *device1* using the MQTT protocol directly to the Azure IoT Hub via the **MQTTnet Version 2.4.0** library:

```
using MQTTnet;
using MQTTnet.Core;
using MQTTnet.Core.Client;
using MQTTnet.Core.Packets;
using MQTTnet.Core.Protocol;
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var options = new MqttClientTcpOptions()
            {                
                Server = "myIoTHub.azure-devices.net",
                Port = 8883,
                ClientId = "device1",
                UserName = "myIoTHub.azure-devices.net/device1/api-version=2018-06-30",              
                Password = "SharedAccessSignature sr=myIoTHub.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2Fdevice1&sig=****&se=1592830262",               
                ProtocolVersion = MQTTnet.Core.Serializer.MqttProtocolVersion.V311,
                TlsOptions = new MqttClientTlsOptions() { UseTls = true },
                CleanSession = true
            };

            var factory = new MqttClientFactory();
            var mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient();

            // handlers
            mqttClient.Connected += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            };
            mqttClient.Disconnected += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
            };
            mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceived += delegate (object sender, MqttApplicationMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload));
            };

            mqttClient.ConnectAsync(options).Wait();

            // subscribe on the topics
            var topicFilters = new[] {
                new TopicFilter("devices/device1/messages/devicebound/#", MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce),
                new TopicFilter("$iothub/twin/PATCH/properties/desired/#", MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce),
                new TopicFilter("$iothub/methods/POST/#", MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce)
            };
            mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(topicFilters).Wait();


            // publish message 
            var topic = $"devices/device1/messages/events/$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8";
            var payload = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello IoT Hub");
            var message = new MqttApplicationMessage(topic, payload, MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce, false);
            mqttClient.PublishAsync(message);

            Console.Read();
        }       
    }
}
```

and the following screen snippet shows an example of the output for updating a desired twin property *color* and receiving a *C2D message*:

[image]